# Multiply columns with range between 0 and 1 by 100 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Given a Pandas dataframe:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                    'B': [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], 
                    'C': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]})

   A    B   C
0  1  0.1  11
1  2  0.2  12
2  3  0.3  13
3  4  0.4  14
4  5  0.5  15
```

For all of the columns where the range of values is between 0 and 1, I'd like to multiply all values in those columns by a constant (say, 100). I don't know a priori which columns have values between 0 and 1 and there are 100+ columns.

```
   A    B   C
0  1   10  11
1  2   20  12
2  3   30  13
3  4   40  14
4  5   50  15
```

I've tried using .min() and .max() and compared them to the desired range to return True/False values for each column.

```
(df.min() >= 0) & (df.max() <= 1)

A    False
B     True
C    False
```

but it isn't obvious how to then select the True columns and multiply those values by 100.

**Update**

I came up with this solution instead

```
col_names = ((df.min() >= 0) & (df.max() <= 1)).index
df[col_names] = df[col_names] * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
to_multiply = [col for col in df if 1 >= min(df[col]) >= 0 and 1 >= max(df[col]) >= 0]

df[to_multiply] = df[to_multiply] * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

We can construct a boolean mask that test if the values in the df are greater than ([`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html#pandas.DataFrame.gt)) 0 and less than ([`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html#pandas.DataFrame.lt)) 1 and then call [`np.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) and pass `axis=0` to generate a boolean mask to filter the columns and then multiply all values in that column by 100:

```
In [58]:

df[df.columns[np.all(df.gt(0) & df.lt(1),axis=0)]] *= 100
df
Out[58]:
   A   B   C
0  1  10  11
1  2  20  12
2  3  30  13
3  4  40  14
4  5  50  15
```

Breaking the above down:

```
In [61]:

df.gt(0) & df.lt(1)
Out[61]:
       A     B      C
0  False  True  False
1  False  True  False
2  False  True  False
3  False  True  False
4  False  True  False
In [62]:

np.all(df.gt(0) & df.lt(1),axis=0)
Out[62]:
array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [63]:

df.columns[np.all(df.gt(0) & df.lt(1),axis=0)]
Out[63]:
Index(['B'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [update](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) your DataFrame based on your selection criteria:

```
df.update(df.loc[:, (df.ge(0).all() & df.le(1).all())].mul(100))

>>> df
     A   B   C
0    1  10  11
1    2  20  12
2    3  30  13
3    4  40  14
4    5  50  15
```

Any column which is greater than or equal to zero and less than or equal to one is multiplied by 100.

Other comparison operators:

- .ge (greater than or equal to)
- .gt (greater than)
- .le (less than or equal to)
- .lt (less than)
- .eq (equals)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.all()` to check if all values are within range and if true, multiply them -

```
In [1877]: paste
for col in df.columns:
        if (0<df[col]).all() and (df[col]<1).all():
                df[col] = df[col] * 100

## -- End pasted text --

In [1878]: df
Out[1878]: 
   A   B   C
0  1  10  11
1  2  20  12
2  3  30  13
3  4  40  14
4  5  50  15
```